# Flutter http post request to firebase database API result in 404

Tags: firebase, http, flutter, dart

I am trying to use the firebase realtime database API in the flutter project. While making a POST request to the API via `http` package in the flutter always returns the status code 404 in the `addProduct` method but strange thing is that when using the same API Url to make the POST request via Postman it works. I could not figure out where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.
My model class where I make the POST request

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import '../models/product.dart';

class ProductsModel extends Model{

  final String base_url = 'https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com/';

  List<Product> _products = [];

  int _selectedProductIndex;
  bool _showFavorites = false;

  List<Product> get products {
    return List.from(_products);
  }

  List<Product> get displayedProducts {
    return List.from(_products.where((Product p){
      return p.isFavorite == _showFavorites;
    }));
  }

  int get selectedProductIndex{
    return _selectedProductIndex;
  }

  Product get selectedProduct{
    return _selectedProductIndex == null ? null : _products[_selectedProductIndex];
  }

  bool get displayFavoritesOnly{
    return _showFavorites;
  }

  void addProduct(Product product) {

    final Map<String, dynamic> productData = {
      'title': product.title,
      'description': product.description,
      'price': product.price,
      'imageUri': "http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food",
      'userEmail': product.userEmail,
      'userId': product.userId
    };

    var data = jsonEncode(productData);

    http.post('https://flutter-course-36df8.firebaseio.com/' + 'products.josn', 
    body: data, headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
        }).then((http.Response response){
        // final Map<String, dynamic> d = json.decode(response.body);
        print(response.statusCode);// always prints 404
        print('test');
      _products.add(product);
      _selectedProductIndex = null;
    });

  }

  void deleteProduct(){
    _products.removeAt(_selectedProductIndex);
    _selectedProductIndex = null;
  }

  void updateProduct(Product product){
    _products[_selectedProductIndex] = product;
    _selectedProductIndex = null;
  }

  void selectProduct(int index){
    _selectedProductIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleProductFavoriteStatus(){
    final bool isCurrentlyFavorite = selectedProduct.isFavorite;
    final bool newFavoriteStatus = ! isCurrentlyFavorite;

    final Product updatedProduct = Product(
      title: selectedProduct.title,
      description: selectedProduct.description,
      price: selectedProduct.price,
      imageUri: selectedProduct.imageUri,
      userEmail: selectedProduct.userEmail,
      userId: selectedProduct.userId,
      isFavorite: newFavoriteStatus
    );

    _products[_selectedProductIndex] = updatedProduct;
    _selectedProductIndex = null;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleDisplayMode(){
    _showFavorites = ! _showFavorites;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your url? `products.josn`? Maybe `json`?

Comment: +1 to typo. There's probably no reason to be going this manually via HTTP instead of using FlutterFire either. Just creating a lot more work for yourself and losing the optimizations, caching, offline persistence, and realtime aspects of the Firebase SDKs.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks...It is my bad...should have paid more attention to the URL.

Comment: @Kato Thanks for your response. I am already aware of that it just that I am learning flutter & wanted to explore the http package.